# Angular: How to put 2 async subscriptions in ngIf with common else condition

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a use case wherein I have 2 async subbscriptions with a common else condition.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{ data1: data1$ | async, data2: data2$ | async } as history; else loader">
<h2>Inside ngIf condition</h2>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loader>Loader here....</ng-template>
```

What's happening here is the content inside the async subscription is being displayed even before the subscription. I understand that is because of the object literal definition of multiple subscriptions.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: your'e create an object "on fly", so the "*ngIf" is always true. You can create an inner div with `*ngIf="history.data1 && history.data2"` -or split in severals: `*ngIf="history.data1"` and `*ngIf="history.data2"`

Comment: Thanks, @Eliseo, just did that. It works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem

Something like what you've written is pretty ambiguous.
I'm not sure what semantics you're trying to achieve.

There are many ways to merge Observables (merge, withLatestFrom, forkJoin, zip,  etc).
You'll likely have to pick and implement one yourself. Be sure to read the documentation.

#### Example:

`forkJoin` [[doc]](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin), for example, doesn't emit until its source Observables all complete.

In your component:

```ts
joinedData$ = forkJoin({
  data1: this.data1$,
  data2: this.data2$
});
```

Markup

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(joinedData$ | async) as history; else loader">
<h2>Inside ngIf condition</h2>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loader>Loader here....</ng-template>
```